# How to open a file and make it default in VBA

Tags: vba, shell

I am trying to make "python.py" to open in notepad each time...I have got the code that does that but how to make it as default..so next time if the user wants to open the python file in notepad, it should open in notepad all the time using VBA and only after the code is excecuted...please find the code below for opening a python file in notepad..

```
Shell "notepad C:\Users\stackoverflow\Desktop\python.py", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: I don't have all the details handy, so it's just a comment, but your code needs to make a registry change somewhere in hkey_classes_root.

Comment: Joel is correct, but *why* would you want to do this? They're user settings for a reason. I would be pretty pissed if somebody's code was mucking around with my settings like that.

Comment: So I understand, do you want the python.py to open in notepad every time you open notepad, or do you want python.py to in notepad through another application, such as Excel, when you execute VBA from that application?

Comment: thank you all for your comments...@Joel, thank you for your suggestion but i would prefer not to do it as I am making a tool for everyone to use..@RubberDuck, you are right..i think the same too...@Edward, I want python.py to open in notepad everytime one opens python.py...thanks plasma33

Answer (score 0):

You could try a VBA macro attached to a button that does this. But I am unsure if this is what you are asking for.

```
Sub LetterChecklist()    

Dim strPath As String
Dim strProgram As String

    strPath = "\\aw\data\Letters\2099_Correspondence\Incoming Letters\.pdf"
    strProgram = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"

    Call Shell("""" & strProgram & """ """ & strPath & """", vbNormalFocus)


End Sub
```